# Redis master-slave and Lua script which alter state challenges

Tags: lua, redis

I have a redis script for key lookup that looks up an item in redis, if it does not find it, does a `zincrby` on another key which is a `zset` for the missing key.

I have a redis master/slave setup where I am using the master to handle all the writes and use the slave node for all the reads.

The lua script when accessed from the slave results in an exception since the slave node is read-only and the `zincrby` call fails.

I dont want to make round trips from the client to the redis server (once for the lookup and another for the `zincrby` because of network latency issues (having a WAN with latency between the client and redis server).  What other options do I have to solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: As there is a write in this script, should it be executed against the master and not the slaves?

Comment: You are right but I want to distribute the load by letting clients connect to the slave and that is where I am having a problem.

Comment: Consider the use of **partitioning** to distribute the load. You can read more [here:](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning)

Comment: @danielgpm I am not sure how that would help me in a Master slave setup.  I understand that partitioning can help in spreading out the load - how is that relevant to my problem?

Comment: @vivekv you mentioned that you wanted to distribute the load, as your original need was some sort of master-master replication that is NOT currently supported in redis. If you still want to make your slave writetable, just configure as `slave-read-only no`

Comment: @vivekv I am facing the same challenge.Did you figured out the solution?If yes,can you share with us?